# How to run a job after the jobs in a cron is completed in node js

Tags: node.js, cron

I want to run a job in node js after completion of all the jobs within a cron job.

I am using `node-schedule` for running a cron job in node js. How to determine the completion of jobs in cron ?

Comment: The one solution is when one job completes to hit the database and put the  flag of this job is true and check in every job completion is all flags are competed .when all jobs are done and flags of all the jobs is completed then call the your another job which you want run completion of all jobs..thnks

Answer (score 0):

After all the cron jobs add one more cron to execute a script that can trigger your node js task.